# EdDSAPublicKey Serialization Java

Tags: java, encoding, digital-signature, public-key, elliptic-curve

Is there a way to serialize EdDSAPublicKey in java.

There a method `getEncoded()` in `EdDSAPublicKey` but how to get back a `EdDSAPublicKey` from the encoding.

Comment: With the [`KeyFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyFactory.html) and `KeySpec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the X509EncodedKeySpec

```
    X509EncodedKeySpec specPub = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encodedPublicKey);
    EdDSAPublicKey eddsakey = new EdDSAPublicKey(specPub);
```

Comment: The above method worked very well for `EdDSAPublicKey`. But `X509EncodedKeySpec` doesn't help in decodeing `EdDSAPrivateKey`. Is there a way to decode `EdDSAPivateKey`

Comment: @Subhankar For private key you have to use the `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`:   `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec specPub = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encodedPrivateKey);
  EdDSAPrivateKey eddsakey = new EdDSAPrivateKey(specPub);`